# HTML Safari background-color only works while at a certain size

Tags: html, css, safari

This is how the website looks like on Microsoft Edge:
[image]

In Safari, it looks like this:
[image]

However, when I resize the Safari window below a certain width/height, it works as expected.
[image]

The website works fine on iOS Safari. You can check it out by yourself: https://readnpay.netlify.app/

This is my CSS:

```css
html {
background-image: url("images/background.png");
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: center;
background-size: cover;
background-blend-mode: overlay;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-top: auto;
}
```

My Safari version is the latest (15.5) and I have reloaded the website many times using different domains.

Why is this happening and how could I make Safari apply the correct styling?

Comment: What do you see in the devtools inspect facility in terms of what CSS is being applied?

Comment: @AHaworth The CSS I sent is being applied. There is no change in CSS/HTML when I resize.

Answer (score -1):

```css
html {
background-image: url("images/background.png");
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: center;
background-size: cover;
background-blend-mode: overlay;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body></body>
</html>
```

first for compatibility of background blend mode with safari : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-blend-mode.asp
and, why not just edit the image to give the luminosity you want instead of add a layer of gray on ?

Comment: It's easier to change the opacity when I need to. Thats why I do the opacity with the CSS. For the compatibility with Safari. As I mentioned in my question the Safari version is up-to-date.

Comment: ah ok ^^' good luck